# How would I SELECT this properly in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, sql

I currently have 3 tables. **movies**, **movie_genre**, **genres**. So when I want to join all genres to the movie data I need to perform an **INNER JOIN**, the only problem I currently have is that I need to specify **JSON_ARRAYAGG** on the genre names to make the genres appear in 1 row instead of having duplicated records with only a different genre this is because I want to output it with **PHP**.

```
| title | description | popularity | [genre_1, genre_2]
```

This result is as expected, and this is how I want to have it. The only thing is that my query is kind of complex because I need to specify all the **NON AGGREGRATED** columns and those are way more then I currently show.

```
SELECT movies.title, movies.description, movies.popularity JSON_ARRAYAGG(genres.name) AS genres FROM movies
JOIN movie_genre ON movies.id = movie_genre.movie_id
JOIN genres ON genres.id = movie_genre.genre_id
GROUP BY movies.title, movies.description, movies.popularity
ORDER BY movies.popularity DESC;
```

When I don't specify all the **NON AGGREGRATED** fields in the **GROUP BY** clause I get the following error

```
SELECT list contains NON AGGREGRATED columns
```

Should I disable the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` or should I change my query?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY movies.id`. If you group by the primary key, all the other columns are functionally dependent and you don't have to list them.

Comment: @Barmar worked please create an answer so I can mark it. You have any more explanation on why I don't need to specify all the other columns?

Comment: Can't create an answer once the question is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's explained in the MySQL [documention](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: "Should I disable the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`"  Definitely DO NOT disable it.